# Passport Jwt Strategy Stopped working

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I don't know what happened, but my Passport Jwt Auth is no longer working.

**in app.js**

```
app.use(passport.initialize());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
        secretOrKey: jwtSecret,
        jwtFromRequest: JwtExtract.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
    }, function (payload, done) {
        console.log("Auth : JwtStrategy");
        moduleUser.User.findById(payload._doc._id)
            .exec()
            .then(function (user) {
                    if (user) done(null, user);
                    else done(null, false);
                }
            )
            .catch(function (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            });
    }
));
```

NOTE: console.log("Auth : JwtStrategy"); never gets called

**My Login API**

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.username && req.body.password) {
        moduleUser.User.findOne({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password})
            .exec()
            .then(function (user) {
                if (user) {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        message: 'Login successful',
                        token: 'JWT ' + jwt.sign(user.toObject(), jwtSecret, {expiresIn: '14 days'})
                    });
                } else {
                    res.status(404).json({
                        message: 'Please enter valid login details'
                    });
                }
            })
    } else {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'All information not provided'
        });
    }
});
```

**And my Not working Private route**

```
router.get('/private', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}),
    function (req, res) {
        res.send('respond with a resource!!!!');
    }
);
```

`

**I Always receive 401 as a response**

URL: http://localhost:5000/users/private

Headers-> Authorization: JWT eyJhb......

Am I doing anything wrong here? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Anybody? No help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed

instead of using

`Authorization: JWT eyJhb......`

used

`Authorization: Bearer eyJhb......`

Thanks to [nexig](https://github.com/nexig)